# I am trying Laravel Auth but every time I try to login with right credention it return false

Tags: laravel, authentication

The problem is when I try to login it always false, why is this? I am trying `auth::attempt()` but if always return false. I tried all method but it won't work.

My controller code is:

```
 function checklogin(Request $req) 
    {
        
        $this->validate($req , [
            'email'  => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        $user_data = array(
            'email' => $req->get('email'),
            'password' => $req->get('password')
        );
        //dd($user_data);
        if(Auth::attempt($user_data)){

            return redirect('admin/successlogin');
        }
        else{
            return back()->with('error' , 'Wrong Login Details');
        }
    }
```

my view code

```
<div class="admin_form">
    
    @if(isset(Auth::user()->email))
    <script type="text/javascript">window.location = "/admin/successlogin" </script>
    @endif

    @if($message = Session::get('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">X</button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
    @endif
    @if(count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)

            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif
<form method="post" action="{{ url('admin/checklogin') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }} 
    <h2>Admin Login</h2>

    <input type="text" name="email" class="text-field" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="text" name="password" class="text-field" placeholder="Password" />
    
  <input type="submit"  class="button" value="Log In" />

</form>
</div>
```

I  try every method but it always return false.

Comment: how do you put user in database? I have similar issue. I put user manually with php tinker and hash password with bcript() function, but I have to use "Hash" facade to encrypt password to database

Comment: Like @James said. Please show us how you are creating your Users.

Comment: without encrypting password

Comment: my password field in database is 123456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try create new user and then Auth::attempt()

```
User::create(['email' => 'email', 'password' => Hash::make('password')]);
$auth_test = Auth::attempt(['email' => 'email', 'password' => 'password']);
dd($auth_test);
```

Comment: oh its working ... can you tell what is the problem here

Comment: Maybe you are creating user wrong way, important is working now, but for me i used different hashing for creating users and attempt, so the same password was different after hash and login failed

Comment: but how can we check pasword without hash

Comment: You create user and his password must be hashed in DB and when he will try log in, Auth::attempt() method hash password and compares hashed password from request with hashed password in DB

Comment: Definitely you have to hash users password in DB

Comment: Its compulsory?